# Python Discord Bot Test RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Context.send' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, coroutine

I'm trying to learn how to code a Discord Bot, however am coming up on this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Context.send' was never awaited
  ctx.send('Hello')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Here is my code (I have omitted the bot token for obvious reasons):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

bot.run("INSERT_BOT_TOKEN")
```

Initially, I was experiencing issues with the PATH for Python. So, I uninstalled Python, cleared the environment Path, etc. Then, I redownloaded it from the official website, and checked the box to auto create a path in installation, however, I receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost correct but with the newest version of discord.py you should be doing.

`pip install discord.py`
`pip install asyncio`

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.start("Insert_token")

asyncio.run(main())
```

You could also try this:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
   try:
      await ctx.send("Hello!")
   except Exception as e:
      print(f"Error: {e}")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.start("Insert_token")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Hopefully this solved your issues if not please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I still receive the same issue. If it's worth noting, the bot runs, and appears online once the program is ran, but when entering "$test" into the chat, the RuntimeWarning shows up.

Comment: Are you using replit? If so you are most likely being rate limited and most IPs replit loads are banned/suspended now.